# Replacing data in a pandas dataframe column based on condition, skipping if condition not met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe with a column of numbers. If the number is less than 0, I would like to add 3.14 to that number. If not, I would like to skip that number and leave it as is. I am using pandas and numpy but cannot find out how to just skip the numbers not meeting the condition while leaving them in the dataframe as is.

When trying this:

```
df['rad'].apply(lambda x: [y if y>=0 else y+3.14 for y in x])
```

I get TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Even though the numbers in 'rad' column are all int64.

Comment: Your *immediate* problem is `apply` is applied *to each element*. So `df['rad'].apply(lambda x: x if x >=0 else x+3.14)` would work. Of course, `np.where` or `pd.Series.where` with a vectorised solution is better..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is `np.where`

```
np.where(df['rad']>0,df['rad'],df['rad']+3.14)
```